# Cloudwatch filter works in console, but not in boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using the boto3 logs client to find a specific log stream that contains a string. It is fairly simple, it is the "requestID" that lambda prints to the log when it first starts. When I filter on the console with a simple requestID string like "3f2d1c8c-4ddf-4c67-a57f-5cec3e3e8739", it works and returns the correct log stream.

When filtering through the boto3 API, it returns nothing despite the API showing that it fully searched that log stream.

```
log_events_resp = logs_client.filter_log_events(
        logGroupName='/aws/lambda/my-function-name',
        filterPattern="3f2d1c8c-4ddf-4c67-a57f-5cec3e3e8739"
    )
```

what am I doing wrong? below is string I want to search for

> START RequestId: edca5feb-2c21-4c47-bc7c-562515094058 Version: $LATEST

is the above a special part of the log in where it can't be search via boto3 or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much experimentation, I have a working solution that is reliably returning results as I expect.

Here is the working code, then I'll explain:

```
def search_log_streams(log_group, request_id, start_time):
    func_frame_obj = log.log_function_info(locals())

    log_streams = []

    log_events_resp = logs_clt.filter_log_events(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        filterPattern=f'"{request_id}"',
        startTime=start_time
    )

    log_streams.extend(log_events_resp["events"])

    try:
        while log_events_resp["nextToken"]:
            log_events_resp = logs_clt.filter_log_events(
                logGroupName=log_group,
                filterPattern=f'"{request_id}"',
                startTime=start_time,
                nextToken=log_events_resp["nextToken"]
            )

            logit.debug(f'log_events_resp: {log_events_resp}')

            log_streams.extend(log_events_resp["events"])

    except KeyError:
        logit.debug(f'no continuation token, all logs streams have been searched')

    log.log_function_results(func_frame_obj, log_streams)
    return log_streams
```

This function takes in a log_group name, the request_id, and start_time (expressed in milliseconds since epoch, as defined in the docs [[see here]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.filter_log_events))

I'm not sure if double wrapping the filterPattern value is what has helped, or if it is finally getting the startTime right. This took a lot of experimentation in order to figure out how to estimate the timestamp of the log I was looking for (the one that contained the request_id) from the event data that was feeding this lambda.

I appreciate the help and time @Jonathan Leon

Comment: glad you got it to work. i'll add this to my toolset!

Comment: I had a similar issue. Sometimes the response may have empty `events`, but if it contains `nextToken`, then you can include it in the subsequent calls to fetch the relevant events which you did in your example.
This behaviour is described in the doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html

Answer (score 1):

I misread your search criteria as a logstream name, rather than string inside the log message. Here's an update for you to consider. For some reason, I run this and get an empty response and then run it a few more times and it returns a response. Very odd, but it does work.

Also note I could only get it to work with at least the logStreamNamePrefix below. When I left it out, I couldn't get a response.

```
client = boto3.client('logs')
logGroupName = '/your/loggroup'
logStreamNamePrefix = '2020/12/'
client.filter_log_events(
        logGroupName=logGroupName,
        logStreamNamePrefix=logStreamNamePrefix,
        filterPattern='7361a40d-2250-4b9a-9780-0f9feac0bb9'   
        )
```

Abbreviated output:

```
{'events': [],
 'searchedLogStreams': [{'logStreamName': '2020/12/01/[$LATEST]1030c0eafc5a4c17acbc96ad984f773',
   'searchedCompletely': True},
  {'logStreamName': '2020/12/01/[$LATEST]19a7a5a60ce549088745ad2fad97def',
   'searchedCompletely': True},
  {'logStreamName': '2020/12/01/[$LATEST]2ac67cb0bfa24e7880ca1ffb97a32d1',
   'searchedCompletely': True},
  {'logStreamName': '2020/12/01/[$LATEST]34f065d3da0490b816d84f8e16d44d0',
   'searchedCompletely': True},
  {'logStreamName': '2020/12/01/[$LATEST]3e26db9628ec43e88562284119514e2',
   'searchedCompletely': True},
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I thought you might be on to something but when I did some additional testing, it doesn't add up. If you look at the top of the window in the console (the new version) where you can "search across all events", it has a link to here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#matching-terms-events) which refers to matching terms in the events.

Comment: Misread your search criteria. See the updated answer.

Comment: I've been playing around with this a lot and it seems to be hit or miss. I am using start time along with the filter and it returns what it is supposed to most of the time, but not all. I might open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There are several weird things going on with boto3 (v 1.26). Here's my code:

```
    if not next_token:
        response = cloudwatch.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group,
            logStreamNames=[log_stream],
            filterPattern=f'"{pattern}"',
            startTime=int(start_dt_utc.timestamp() * 1000),
            endTime=int(end_dt_utc.timestamp() * 1000),
            limit=MAX_RESPONSE_LOG_EVENTS, 
        )
    else:
        response = cloudwatch.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group,
            logStreamNames=[log_stream],
            filterPattern=f'"{pattern}"',
            # startTime=int(start_dt_utc.timestamp() * 1000),
            # endTime=int(end_dt_utc.timestamp() * 1000),
            nextToken=next_token,
            limit=MAX_RESPONSE_LOG_EVENTS,
        )
```

1. I always get fewer events than `limit`. To get ~100 logs I have to
   make ~10 calls to cloudwatch. So you have to assume the response is paginated not matter what.
2. If you specify `startTime` and `endTime` in subsequent calls (ie, the else block above), the responses are incorrect- half the events are missing.
3. If you *don't* specify `filterPattern` or `logStreamNames` in subsequent calls, you get far *more* events than you should.
4. Filter pattern must be enclosed in double quotes, or else it has no effect.
5. Special characters are not allowed in the filter pattern. Escaping with `\` doesn't work.